# How can one indicate to protobuf-net that an interface property should be deserialized as a particular concrete type?

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

I have this property:

```
public class SomeClass
{
  public ISomeInterface SomeProperty { get;set; }
}
```

Now, `ISomeInterface` in this particular context can only be a specific concrete type, like `SomeClass2`. Can I do it without the ProtoInclude attribute?

I thought I can do something like this:

```
model.Add(typeof(SomeClass), true).Add(1, "SomeProperty", typeof(SomeClass2));
```

Indicating, that `SomeProperty` should always be deserialized as `SomeClass2` (which, of course, implements the interface).

But I failed to find a method like this on the model.

Comment: I'm not at a PC at the moment, but what you are after is the default-type. I'll be back later to check if that is easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

You are out to test me ;p

That wasn't directly exposed; google isn't letting me commit at the moment, but the following will work as soon as I can commit:

```
[Test]
public void ExposeInterfaceWithDefaultImplementation()
{
    var model = TypeModel.Create();
    // note the following sets for the ConstructType for the ISomeInferface, not specifically for Foo
    model.Add(typeof(ISomeInterface), false).Add("Foo").ConstructType = typeof(SomeClass2);
    model.Add(typeof(SomeClass), false).Add("SomeProperty");

    var orig = new SomeClass();
    orig.SomeProperty = new SomeClass2();
    orig.SomeProperty.Foo = 123;
    var clone = (SomeClass)model.DeepClone(orig);
    Assert.AreEqual(123, clone.SomeProperty.Foo);
}
```

Comment: (note that this still only considers the **interface** members, to avoid surprises; by the nature of an interface, any type implementing the interface should be accepted; the specified type is *only* used if it needs to deserialize, and the value is `null`)

Comment: I did not understand the last statement, specifically "and the value is null". What if the value is not null? How does the deserializer know which type to instantiate from the stream, if neither ProtoInclude, nor DynamicType were used?

Comment: Is there a conceptual problem with allowing per property specification of the default interface implementation type? All I want is that when a property is serialized the actual type is processed and when deserialized the specific concrete type is instantiated.